# iOS multiple XIB in a View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, viewcontroller

I have a View Controller that displays 3 custom views. My question is, would it be better to create a XIB for each subview or not?

I have been told that loading a XIB file is really expensive, so it's better to have just one XIB for the View Controller and avoid having XIB for the custom views in that controller. However, in order to avoid that, I have seen the custom views' constraints set by code (as there is no XIB for them and no way to use the IB), which I don't like. That's why I'm wondering if it's fine (both a good practice and **efficient**) to create a XIB for each subview and set then set the constraints using the IB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are planning on destroying views with a large amount of components and rebuilding them serval times a second you should not notice any performance hit. If you do, cache them.

As for best practice (in my option) you don't use XIBs for the efficiency, you mainly use them because they are quicker to build and easier to understand if you need to revisit the view at a later date.

If your going to use AutoLayout in code anyway I would use XIBs where possible as you get the advantages above. The layout engine is usually the expensive part anyway.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Martin. So does the layout engine take part only when using Autolayout/IB, or also if we set them by code? I'm not going to do that, as you end up with loads of lines and it's really hard to figure out the result, but just to know if it's more efficient setting them by code rather than on the IB (both the "old" and the Autolayout ones).

Comment: All constraints are the same if they are created in the xib or in code. I would not worry too much amount the 'cost' of AutoLayout though as you usually only see the difference between AutoLayout and setting frames manually if you need to update views positions very regularly i.e. every frame.